# How to declare a variable inside an if condition?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a function MyFunction that returns a value from 0 to 10. 0 indicates a success and nonzero a failure. If I want to display a MessageBox with the value only when it's nonzero I have to do the following:

```
int e = MyFunction();
if (e != 0) { MessageBox(e); }
```

If I want to have the variable int e to be local without causing redefinition (because I'm bad at naming or something) I can enclose the whole thing in curly braces and isolate the variable like so:

```
int e;
{ int e = MyFunction(); if (e != 0) { MessageBox(e); } }
```

Is it however possible to compress this into a single if statement instead like so:

```
if (int e = MyFunction() != 0) { MessageBox(e); } //obviously does not work as intended
```

I know if statements don't really work this way but is it possible to do it anyway by using some c++ magic? It may sound trivial to you guys but I really want to do this. I did search, also asked, but no dice. Thanks!

Comment: _... c++ magic ..._ Ask the unicorn.

Comment: _because I'm bad at naming or something_ hmm... :)

Comment: What about using exceptions for error management?

Comment: You can try this: `if (MyFunction()) { MessageBox(e); }`. In C++, any nonzero is always `true`.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh You noticed the `e` here: `MessageBox(e);`?

Comment: Thanks πάντα ῥεῖ, I missed it. It seems impossiple. If `MessageBox(int)` depends on `int e`, I think you can call `MessageBox(MyFunction())`, and modify `MessageBox(int)`, it could be `MessageBox(int e) { if (e != 0) //do something}`

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh: That would be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
if(int e = MyFunction())
{
    MessageBox(e);
}
```

This works because `int` naturally converts to `bool` so the `if()` succeeds when `e` is any *non-zero* value (or if it converts to `true` bool value).

The benefit of this is that you don't litter the surrounding scope with error return values. Though it may not be as immediately obvious to some coders as separating the function call from the test.

Comment: Some people consider this kind of implicit truthiness condition to be unclear/poor form, particularly in C++. I'm not necessarily one of them.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not entirely decided on the issue. There is at least one proposal for status return types with optional value that facilitates this style. I do think the fact that it clears up the surrounding scope is valuable and may contribute to reducing bugs from shared return code variables and variable litter in general.

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

Your second snippet of code is the proper/correct/best/clearest/easiest way to do it.

Don't try to be too clever.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you wanted, but if the cause is only in record appearance you can use `for` instead `if`:

```
for(int e = MyFunction(); e!=0; e=0) MessageBox(e);
```

BUT I'm not sure there are any reasons to replace normal clear code to statements like this. Nobody will recommend you such solutions.